# if $f$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb D$ then it is equal to its power series in all $\Bbb D$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I saw a solution to some question somewhere and this was implicitly used.

I know holomorphic functions are given **LOCALLY**   by their taylor series, but from the fact that $f\in Hol(\Bbb D)$ can we conclude that $f$ is given in all $\Bbb D$ by its taylor series at $0$?

In particular, how can we be sure that its taylor series at $0$ converges in all $\Bbb D$ and only in some disk around $0$ $B\subsetneq \Bbb D$?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $\Omega$ and $z_0 \in \Omega$ then the Taylor expansion around $z_0$ is valid in the largest open disk around $z_0$ contained in $\Omega$. So the answer to your question is YES.

Comment: why is that? How does one prove that?

Comment: Almost any book on Complex Analysis has a proof of this basic result. You can look at Rudin's RCA>.

Comment: That's a standard Complex Analysis theorem. Do you want a reference?